# Why is the combination of LangChain's ConversationSummaryMemory and ConversationalRetrievalQAChain not returning the correct results?

Tags: langchain

I'm using LangChain's ConversationSummaryMemory and ConversationalRetrievalQAChain together to build a conversational AI system. However, I'm encountering some issues with the results returned by OpenAI.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    f1d856b7-1e5d-49ff-ba1f-3928ac3d4b35    INFO    {
    response1: { text: 'Hi Jim! How can I assist you today?' },
    memory: { chat_history: [ [SystemChatMessage] ] }
    }
    f1d856b7-1e5d-49ff-ba1f-3928ac3d4b35    INFO    {
    response2: { text: 'My name is OpenAI Assistant.' },
    memory: { chat_history: [ [SystemChatMessage] ] }
    }
```

```
   export const handler = async () => {
   const { model, pinecone, pineconeIndex } = await initClient();
   const memory = new ConversationSummaryMemory({
      llm: model,
      memoryKey: "chat_history",
      returnMessages: true,
   });

   const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
      new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
      {
         pineconeIndex: pineconeIndex,
      }
   );

   const chain = ConversationalRetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(
      model,
      vectorStore.asRetriever(5, { id: "01234567890" }),
      {
         memory,
         options: {
            returnSourceDocuments: true,
         },
      }
   );
   const question1 = "Hi! I'm Jim.";
   const response1 = await chain.call({
      question: question1,
   });

   await memory.saveContext({ input: question1 }, { output: response1.text });
   console.log({
      response1: response1,
      memory: await memory.loadMemoryVariables(),
   });
   const question2 = "What's my name?";
   const response2 = await chain.call({
      question: question2,
   });
   await memory.saveContext({ input: question2 }, { output: response2.text });
   console.log({
      response2: response2,
      memory: await memory.loadMemoryVariables(),
   });
   };
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the combination of ConversationSummaryMemory and ConversationalRetrievalQAChain is not returning the correct results from OpenAI? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!